# setting RecordType in Test Coverage

Tags: apex, code-coverage, record-type, failing-tests, getter

I am having trouble on a test that is setting a record type. I believe I am setting the record type the correct way, the test is passing, but my test coverage is telling me that no record type was set. How am I setting the record type incorrectly in the test?

```
static testMethod void test6(){
    RecordType rt = [Select Id, Name From RecordType Where SobjectType = 'advpm__Matter__c' AND Name = 'Litigation'];
    Account a = new Account(Name = 'test');
    insert a;
    Opportunity o = new Opportunity(AccountId = a.Id, CloseDate = Date.today(), Name = 'test', StageName = 'Identified');
    insert o;
    Case c = new Case(Opportunity__c = o.Id, Status = 'Open');
    insert c;
    advpm__Matter__c matter = new advpm__Matter__c(RecordTypeId = rt.Id, Case__c = c.Id,Date_of_Default__c = null, Outstanding_Balance__c = null, Rush__c= true, Concurrent_Deal__c=true);

    Test.startTest();
    MatterIntakeScreen controllerClass = new MatterIntakeScreen(new ApexPages.StandardController(c));
    controllerClass.setRecordTypes('Litigation');
    controllerClass.getRecordTypes();
    controllerClass.saveMatter();
    Test.stopTest();
    system.assertEquals(controllerClass.getRecordTypes(), 'Litigation');
}
```

[image]

[image]

```
public class MatterIntakeScreen{

public advpm__Matter__c matter   {get; set;}
public String errorMessage       {get; set;}

Case cs;

public MatterIntakeScreen(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
    cs = (Case)sc.getRecord();
    cs = [SELECT Id, Status, AccountId, Account.Name, Account.Legal_Status__c, Legal_Name__c,RecordType.Name,  
            Merchant_Number__c, Funded_Amount__c, Address__c, Fund_Date__c, Opportunity__c, Type, LP_Loan__c 
            FROM Case WHERE Id =: cs.Id];
    errorMessage = null;
    if(cs.Status == 'Closed'){
        errorMessage = 'Case is already Closed.';
        cs.addError(errorMessage);
    }
    matter = new advpm__Matter__c();
}

private boolean formIsValid() {
    boolean isValid = true;
        if (cs.Status == 'Closed') {
            cs.addError('Case is already Closed.');
            isValid = false;
            return isValid;
        }

        List<RecordType> recordTypeList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE Id = :recordTypes];
        if(recordTypeList.size() > 0 ){
            if(recordTypeList[0].Name == 'Litigation' || recordTypeList[0].Name == 'Bankruptcy' || recordTypeList[0].Name == 'Litigation - BK') {
                if (matter.Date_of_Default__c == null) {
                    matter.Date_of_Default__c.addError('You must enter a value');
                    isValid = false;
                    return isValid;
                }
                if (matter.Outstanding_Balance__c == null) {
                    matter.Outstanding_Balance__c.addError('You must enter a value');
                    isValid = false;
                    return isValid;
                }
            }
        }
    return isValid;
}

public PageReference saveMatter(){
    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();

    try{
        if (formIsValid() == false){
            return null;
        }
        cs.Status = 'Closed';
        update cs;
        matter.advpm__Primary_Account__c  = cs.AccountId;

        if(cs.RecordType.Name.equals('Portfolio Management')){
            matter.advpm__Matter_Number__c = cs.Merchant_Number__c;
        }
        matter.Loan_Amount__c = cs.Funded_Amount__c;
        matter.Address_of_borrower__c = cs.Address__c;
        matter.Date_of_Loan__c= cs.Fund_Date__c;
        matter.Case__c = cs.Id;
        matter.advpm__Opportunity__c = cs.Opportunity__c;
        matter.LP_Loan__c = cs.LP_Loan__c;
        if(recordTypes != null){
            matter.RecordTypeId = recordTypes;
        }
        insert matter;
        system.debug('newly inserted matter:: ' + matter);
        ....
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.debug('ex----'+ex);
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);           
        Database.rollback(sp);
        return null;
    }   
}

String recordTypes;
public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(6);
    for(RecordType rt : [Select Id, Name From RecordType Where SobjectType = 'advpm__Matter__c' AND Name != 'Enforcement' AND Name != 'Standard']) {
        if(rt.Name == 'Litigation') {
            options.set(0, new SelectOption(rt.Id, rt.Name));
        }
        else if(rt.Name == 'Bankruptcy'){
            options.set(1, new SelectOption(rt.Id, rt.Name));
        }
        else if(rt.Name == 'Litigation - BK'){
            options.set(2, new SelectOption(rt.Id, rt.Name));
        }
        else if(rt.Name == 'Defense'){
            options.set(3, new SelectOption(rt.Id, rt.Name));
        }
        else if(rt.Name == 'Records Requests'){
            options.set(4, new SelectOption(rt.Id, rt.Name));
        }
        else {
            options.add(new SelectOption(rt.Id, rt.Name));
        }
    }
    return options;
}

public String getRecordTypes() {
    return recordTypes;
}

public void setRecordTypes(String recordTypes) {
    this.recordTypes = recordTypes;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please include the relevant lines of code from `MatterIntakeScreen` that you're calling here as text, rather than an image? It's hard to follow the flow of control and not all of the important code is shown here.

Comment: Check the recordTypes variable used in formIsValid(). I suspect, based on the highlighting, that the query for the recordTypes returns an empty list

Comment: In your class, where are the values for "recordTypes" and "matter" being set?  In your test class, where is "matter" (about line 9) being used?

Comment: @Jochen you are right the query is returning an empty list which is why it can't get past. But the confusing thing is when I query for the list in dev console there are records. But it is just not picking up when I use the describe object or write the query in the test class.

Comment: @DavidReed I updated the post with the MatterIntakeScreen class

Comment: Isn't your query `SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE Id = :recordTypes` looking for an `Id`, whereas you are setting a `String` value in the variable?

Comment: An addition to other comments you also have this line: "matter.RecordTypeId = recordTypes;" .   Change "controllerClass.setRecordTypes('Litigation');"  to "controllerClass.setRecordTypes(rt.Id);" in test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the issue seems to be on this line in your test class:

```
controllerClass.setRecordTypes('Litigation');
```

The query as I see in your `MatterIntakeScreen#formIsValid()`, is as:

```
List<RecordType> recordTypeList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE Id = :recordTypes];
```

where you are fetching details based on the Record Type `Id`.

If you have set the `recordTypes` as a String value, the query above will never return any value and thus your execution will not get into the flow.

Either of the places needs a change, either you pass an appropriate record type id to the query, or (better approach) you change your query to accept a record type name/developer name.

Comment: very interesting. My `recordTypes` variable is a string. It is working in practice so I thought ID's and String were interchangeable with binded values. I will play around with this and see if anything moves

Comment: String and Ids are interchangeable, provided String consists of the actual `Id` value. But in your case it's just a string literal which will not have any match with any `Id` and thus won't return any result.

Comment: Glad that it helped. It just needed few iterations to understand how `recordTypes` are being populated.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the highlighting, the query to the RecordType object (table) didn't return any rows.

Using an object describe to get the record type and it's ID is a better solution here and will probably also solve your issue.

The reason for this is that if there are no records of this type in the org yet, the RecordType object won't have any data in it. A describe of the object on the other hand, will always return its record types even if you haven't created any records of that type yet.

Assuming the developer name of the Record Type is `Litigation`

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = advpm__Matter__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtInfoMap = d.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName();
Id rtId = rtInfoMap.get('Litigation').getRecordTypeId();
```

Comment: thanks Mark. I have tried this with no success. I believe the issue it coming in because it is being called in the constructor (before the save happens) and the record type is not set before the save. I have the record types being set on a VFP and am pulling them to the controller with a getter and setter method. I will update the question with full details. I am unclear as to why the recordtypes variable is null but the other fields are not null.